# Sed - remove numbers from columns that repeat within the line, but keep the first approach

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a text-file in the following format:

```
c4 c4 r4 c8 c8 e2 e2 c1 
c4 c4 r4 c8 c8 c1 e2 e2 
c4 c4 r4 e2 e2 c8 c8 c1 
c4 c4 r4 e2 e2 c1 c8 c8 
c4 c4 r4 c1 e2 e2 c8 c8 
c4 c4 r4 c1 c8 c8 e2 e2 
c4 c4 c8 c8 r4 e2 e2 c1 
c4 c4 c8 c8 r4 c1 e2 e2 
c4 c4 c8 c8 e2 e2 r4 c1 
c4 c4 c8 c8 e2 e2 c1 r4 
c4 c4 c8 c8 c1 e2 e2 r4 
c4 c4 c8 c8 c1 r4 e2 e2 
c4 c4 e2 e2 c8 c8 r4 c1 
c4 c4 e2 e2 c8 c8 c1 r4 
c4 c4 e2 e2 r4 c8 c8 c1
```

I want to remove all numbers from columns that repeat within the line, but always keep the first approach, also when the value was changed by another number - so the output looks like this:

```
c4 c r c8 c e2 e c1 
c4 c r c8 c c1 e2 e 
c4 c r e2 e c8 c c1 
c4 c r e2 e c1 c8 c 
c4 c r c1 e2 e c8 c 
c4 c r c1 c8 c e2 e 
c4 c c8 c r4 e2 e c1 
c4 c c8 c r4 c1 e2 e 
c4 c c8 c e2 e r4 c1 
c4 c c8 c e2 e c1 r4 
c4 c c8 c c1 e2 e r4 
c4 c c8 c c1 r4 e2 e 
c4 c e2 e c8 c r4 c1 
c4 c e2 e c8 c c1 r4 
c4 c e2 e r4 c8 c c1
```

Possible numbers are (1-64)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU¹ `sed`, you could do:

```
$ sed -Ee ':1;s/(\<[[:alpha:]]([[:digit:]])+\>[[:alpha:][:space:]]*\<[[:alpha:]])\2\>/\1/;t1' < file
c4 c r c8 c e2 e c1
c4 c r c8 c c1 e2 e
c4 c r e2 e c8 c c1
c4 c r e2 e c1 c8 c
c4 c r c1 e2 e c8 c
c4 c r c1 c8 c e2 e
c4 c c8 c r4 e2 e c1
c4 c c8 c r4 c1 e2 e
c4 c c8 c e2 e r4 c1
c4 c c8 c e2 e c1 r4
c4 c c8 c c1 e2 e r4
c4 c c8 c c1 r4 e2 e
c4 c e2 e c8 c r4 c1
c4 c e2 e c8 c c1 r4
c4 c e2 e r4 c8 c c1
```

Same with `perl`:

```
perl -pe '1 while s/\b\pL(\d+)\b[\pL\s]*\b\pL\K\1//' < file
```

In both, we replace `<word-boundary><letter><digits><word-boundary><any-amount-of-letters-and-whitespace><word-boundary><letter><same-digits><word-boundary>` with the same with `<same-digits>` removed and repeat as long as there's a substitution (using `t` or `while`)

---

<sup>¹ the GNUisms in there are `:` commands being followed by another command, in standard `sed` you'd need separate `-e`xpressions, `-E` (actually a BSDism), `\<`/`\>` (actually a ex/vi'ism, some other `sed`s support `[[:<:]]`, `[[:>:]]` or `\b` as equivalents).</sup>